# How do I style the title element within a form?

Tags: forms, css, attributes, title

I am using jQuery validation to make sure my form is submitted properly. I'm trying to style the title element within my form so that when a user doesn't fill at the form properly the text that pops up is red instead of black. My HTML is as follows...

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="E-mail-form.php" name="EmailFromMyWebsite">

                <label for="name">Name</label> <br>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="required" placeholder="Your Name" title=" (Your name is required)"> <br />

                <label for="email">E-mail</label> <br>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="required email" placeholder="Name@email.com" title=" (Your email is required)"> <br />

                <label for="message">Message/Comment</label> <br>
                <textarea name="message" class="required" placeholder="Leave a brief message" title=" (Please leave me a brief message)"></textarea> <br />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" />
        </form>
```

In the CSS I have tried a few things such as

```
#contact[type="title"] {
    color: red;
}

#input[type="title"] {
    color: red;
}

title {
    color: red;
}
```

I also tried just #contact and  which makes the entire form red. I just want the title="" to be red. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: `title` is an attribute, not an element. Submit your form wrong and see what class your jQuery plugin applies to the element that's created.

Comment: You cannot style title text(though, like it is possible to break text), instead you can use jQuery to style them, like for example `tipsy`

Comment: @Blender that makes sense but how do I do that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't style the title attribute on an input element, or any element for that matter. Have a look at [jQueryUI Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). That should help you get some styled tooltips happening.

Comment: Well I was able to change the color of the entire form to red. Is there way to just target the title?

Comment: No, there isn't a way, the title is not an element, it's an attribute to an element. Browsers have their own implementations on how to render these title attributes. If you want styled tooltips, have a look at the link provided in the answer. It works by having jQuery reading the text from the title tag on the element, and then dynamically inserting some newly generated HTML into the DOM which then displays the text from the title attribute. This newly generated bit of HTML will then have class attached to it, which you then can refer to inside your CSS.

Comment: If your using jQuery Validation this css will allow you to change the error message...
    
    label.error {
        color:red;
        padding-left: 5px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

If your using jQuery Validation "label.error" will allow you to style the error message...

```
label.error { 
    color:red; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
}
```